# cant access elements in dynamic web pages

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

hi i have tried to access elements in dynamic web page but i cant..
i have added the code below..

and i have used relative xpath

url is  https://jobs.dxc.technology/page/show/Student-and-New-Grads

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to("https://jobs.dxc.technology/page/show/Student-and-New-Grads");
    Thread.sleep(8000);

    try {

         ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,2650)");
         Thread.sleep(3000);

        //Textbox for First name(i have used relative xpath )
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-friendly-name,'s_FirstName']")).sendKeys("raju");
         //Textbox for last  name
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-friendly-name,'s_LastName']")).sendKeys("123456");
         //Textbox for email 
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-friendly-name,'s_Email']")).sendKeys("raju12@gmail.com");
         //Textbox for phone number 
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-friendly-name,'s_MobileNumber']")).sendKeys("9626092023");
         //drop down for area of interest
         Select interest =new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[starts-with(@id,'contactForm_f') and @size='4']")));
         interest.selectByVisibleText("Applications – JC");
         //drop down for location
         Select location =new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@data-friendly-name,'s_Country']")));
         location.selectByVisibleText("India");
         //radio button
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[starts-with(@id,'contactForm_f') and @type,'radio']")).click();
         //join button           
         driver.findElement(By.name("contactForm$cmd0")).submit();


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can try to be more clear and specific about the issue you are facing by describing more about it. Like by adding some error logs that you received or what else you're getting when you can't access those elements etc.

Comment: hi @NitinGurbani ..the below is the console message

Comment: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(@id,'contactForm_f')]//following::index[2]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Answer (score 0):

Something to try: When using javascriptexecutor you have to handle the inline single quotes in order for the path to find correctly.

```
'//*[contains(@class=\'is-loading\')'
'//*[contains(@id=\'hover-gear\')'
```